# Какие проверки нужно делать перед добавлением данных из формы в БД?

Tags: php, mysql

Какие обязательные проверки нужно делать перед добавлением данных в БД из html формы?

Comment: Все те которые ты можешь представить и никогда не доверять данным, введенным пользователем!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trim(), strip_tags(), (int)`[если надо число].

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_real_escape_string();
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы еще бы посоветовал использовать ereg_replace

Answer (score 1):

проверять данные, чтоб небыло пустых, экранировать, удалять лишее, если надо переводить в строку или число. вообщем то все предыдущие действия, кроме того что сказал [@Ale_x](/users/3785/ale_x), надо выполнить

Answer (score 0):

перехади на PDO для работы с базой

Comment: ИМХО PDO тут не причем, вопрос слишком абстрактный... Если это допустим регистрация то все проверяется регулярками и вообще ненадо никаких `mysql_real_escape_string, strip_tags, trim` и т.д.

PDO не спасет от возможной глупости и(или) неопытности программиста

Comment: потому как PDO часть защиты и проверок (кавыкки к примеру) берет на себя. Я не говорю что PDO это панацея - это всего лишь улучшенный инструмент для работы с БД